# Nodejs parameter charset

Tags: node.js

I am using NodeJS trying to get Chinese parameter from client side, but the value gotten by `var name = req.param('name')` is  messy code, I want to fix the charset to `utf8` but I do not know how to do.

**BACKGROUND**:

front-end: request by `$http` of angular

**TRY**:

`req.setEncoding('utf8')` does not work.

add header parameter `"Accept": "application/json;charset=utf-8"` in `$http`, also doesn't work.

Comment: I think a "minimized failing case" example code for your client and server would be good. If it's also failing on plain HTTP you don't even have to use angular for that demo/example.

Comment: since utf8 chars are encoded in url, did you try `decodeURIComponent` on the param value?

Comment: @hassansin yes, it is not the url encoded code, it did not work. my app is on a Linux server, I suspect if it is the reason because my server do not support UTF-8.

Comment: @Dodekeract  My server is simple I think. basic express app

Comment: @Jesse doesn't mean we're here to reconstruct your code. It's your job to provide us the necessary samples.